# .htaccess redirect between dates

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to add a landingspage on my website. The landingspage is on a subdirectory.
Im using a .htaccess file to redirect from the subdirectory.
The .htaccess contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} <201604071200
RewriteRule ^$ /test [R=302,L]
```

So with this script, site will redirect to the `http://example.com/test` untill seventh of April, 2016, 12:00.

Now I want that AFTER seventh of April, 2016, 12:00, the domain `http://example.com/test` redirect to the home domain `http://example.com`.

How can I achieve this?

Yours,
L

Comment: Use the same line, but `>201604071200`?

Comment: That doesn't make the `/test` directory redirect to my home domain

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/test http://www.example.com [R=302,L]` should do the trick (or just `test`) without the slash, I always forget which is which

Comment: It was without the slash, and that did the trick! Thank you sir!